# When can parentheses be safely omitted in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

Here is a toy example:

```
object Example {

  import collection.mutable
  import collection.immutable.TreeSet

  val x = TreeSet(1, 5, 8, 12)
  val y = mutable.Set.empty ++= x
  val z = TreeSet.empty ++ y
  // This gives an error: unspecified parameter
  //  val z = TreeSet.empty() ++ y

}
```

Apparently `TreeSet.empty` and `TreeSet.empty()` are not the same thing. What's going on under the hood? When can I safely omit (or not omit in this case) the parentheses?

---

#### Update

I have sent some code to the console and then deleted it in intellij before eval the above code, here it is:

```
  implicit object StringOrdering extends Ordering[String] {
    def compare(o1: String, o2: String) = {
      o1.length - o2.length
    }
  }
  object StringOrdering1 extends Ordering[String] {
    def compare(o1: String, o2: String) = {
      o2.length - o1.length
    }
  }
```

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? `TreeSet.empty` complains about diverging implicits for me.

Comment: I am using Scala 2.11.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a special case, and isn't quite relevant to when you can and cannot omit parentheses.

This is the signature for `TreeSet.empty`:

```
def empty[A](implicit ordering: Ordering[A]): TreeSet[A]
```

It has an implicit parameter list that requires an `Ordering` for the contained type `A`. When you call `TreeSet.empty`, the compiler will try to implicitly find the correct `Ordering[A]`.

But when you call `TreeSet.empty()`, the compiler thinks you are trying to explicitly provide the implicit parameter. Except you leave out the parameter in the list, which is a compile error (wrong number of arguments). The only way this will work is if you explicitly pass some `Ordering`: `TreeSet.empty(Ordering.Int)`.

---

*Side note*: Your above code does not actually compile with `TreeSet.empty`, because it succumbs to an ambiguous implicit error for `Ordering`. There is probably some implicit `Ordering[Int]` in your scope that you are not including in the question. It would be better to make the type explicit and use `TreeSet.empty[Int]`.